# Setting the exit node of a tor relay by country

Tags: tor

I'm having some trouble in setting the country of the tor exit nodes. Following [this](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/733/can-i-exit-from-a-specific-country-or-node?newreg=b443bfb9dcb647c9863a7567bf7e03f0) link, by adding the bellow entries to the ./Data/torrc

```
ExitNodes {ru}
StrictNodes 1
```

an exit node from the specified region should be used. However, geo locating the exit nodes shows that none are from Russia. Upon picking a new identity the exit node always remains in the EU or US. Why is that?

Comment: You probably doing everything right but try to use:
    `ExitNodes {RU}`
    `StrictNodes 1`

Comment: @Christos Changing to upper case did not help. The chosen exit node is still in the EU or US

Comment: this isn't an InfoSec question, this is a TOR configuration question: http://tor.stackexchange.com/